# Ruby on Rails, how do parameter-passing to controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, controller, parameter-passing

I have Event Calendar. I have standart link to create new event (it was created in views by scaffolding):

```
<%= link_to 'New Event', new_event_path %>
```

Now I need put same link to each day of calendar table and pass the date as parameter to controller

I do:

```
<%= link_to '+', new_event_path(date) %>
```

And I would like to have it in controller and do something like that

```
  def new
    @event = Event.new

    if params[:date]
      @event.date = params[:date]
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @event }
    end
  end
```

But it doesn't work. If I click to my new link I get the URL like `http://localhost:3000/events/new.2013-04-02`
and a blank page.

How it should be realized correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass additional like this:

```
<%= link_to '+', new_event_path(date: date) %>
```